# как правильно сделать Basic авторизацию? C#, xNet

Tags: c#, header, auth, xnet, basic

> Для выполнения запроса требуется basic авторизация. 
>   Запросы к серверу осуществляются по протоколу HTTPS методом POST
>
> Для идентификации вэб-браузера необходимо прописать заголовок.
>   Примеры заголовков:
>
> `Content-Type: text/xml`
>   **`Authorization: Basic TG9naW46UGFzcw==`**
>   `Accept: text/xml`
>   `Accept-Encoding: *`
>   `...`

---

Как правильнее это реализовать через xNet?

`using (var req = new HttpRequest())
  {
     req.Authorization = "Basic TG9naW46UGFzcw==";`

или

`using (var req = new HttpRequest())
  {
     req.AddParam("Authorization", "Basic TG9naW46UGFzcw==");`

Comment: Если не использовать xNet (откуда вы его взяли ваще и зачем он нужен?), то можно например вот так - https://gist.github.com/bryanbarnard/8102915

Comment: @Monk, благодарю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный ответ - так:
`req.Authorization = "Basic TG9naW46UGFzcw==";`
Но по-моему оба работают, просто этот вариант грамотнее, визуально приятнее и защищает от ошибки в имени заголовка.